# Change button style in MVC5 view

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I use the following view code which I created in MVC5 and I want to change the button style
to be like the forum buttons (e.g. ask question button in this stack forum,add button frame color etc),how should I do that?
currently its just text that when you hoover it with the mouse you see line under it...

```
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New Item", "Create")
</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need css to style a button.

[image]

```
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New Item", "Create", 
        null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "mybtn"})
</p>
<style type="text/css">
    a.mybtn {
        background: #777;
        color: #fff;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 6px 12px 6px 12px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the overload

```
@Html.ActionLink("linktext", "action", "controller", routeValues: new { }, htmlAttributes: new { @class="" })
```

then supply a css class.

Comment: Thanks Jasen voted up ,but I new to this can you please provide example of the css class and how should I create it?

Comment: Win's answer addresses this. If you want to copy SO's button just use the browser's inspect tool and examine the class rules applied to that button.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-labeled btn-info" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action(" Details ", "Movies
",new { id = item.Id})'" data-toggle="modal tooltip" data-target="" title="Details">
<span class="btn-label">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></i>
</span>
Details
```